# Best way to filter a json object or avoid unnecessary nodes

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js

Context : NodeJS Project
I have my json object stored in db like below format.

```
items:[
{name : {"en" : "enName", "fr" : "frName", "zh" : "zhName"},
 image :{"en" : "enImage", "fr" : "frImage", "zh" : "zhImage"}
},
{name : {"en" : "enName", "fr" : "frName", "zh" : "zhName"},
 image :{"en" : "enImage", "fr" : "frImage", "zh" : "zhImage"}
},
{name : {"en" : "enName", "fr" : "frName", "zh" : "zhName"},
 image :{"en" : "enImage", "fr" : "frImage", "zh" : "zhImage"}
}
]
```

I want to pass only locale specific values to client. That means if the request is coming from **France** I don't want to pass **en** and **zh** nodes in response JSON.

Is there any better way to filter the key-value pair rather than iterating through all? Suggestion for a better approach ?

Comment: You have to iterate at some point to modify the list, I would suggest using `map`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: Once you've created the single-locale JSON for each language, *cache* the result so you don't have to run the exact same code for every request. And improve the client so it figures out what language to use and requests it specifically; on the server it should be a static resource.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new JSON object with the values you want. Below is some example code for this:

**NOTE: If you're using MongoDB you should use the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/applications/aggregation/)...**

This code is the JS for the job, but you really need to use the DB engine itself.

```
var newList = [];
var locale = getLocale(); // made up function to find ISO country code, e.g. en, fr

for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    newList.push(
        { 
          name: items[i]['name'][locale]
          image: items[i]['image'][locale]
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Map should do it:

```
var locale = getLocale();
var res = items.map(function (item) {
    if (locale === 'en') {
        return {
            name: { 'en': item.name.en },
            image: { 'en': item.image.en }
        }
    } else if { ... }
});
```

Map lets you transform objects.

Comment: No reason to use multiple `if` statements, you can just use locale as the key for your object.

Answer (score 0):

Use a JSON structure that looks like this instead:

```
itemsByLocale:{
  "en": [{name:"enName", image:"enImage"}, {name:"enName", image:"enImage"}, ...]
  "fr": [{name:"frName", image:"frImage"}, {name:"frName", image:"frImage"}, ...]
  "zh": [{name:"zhName", image:"zhImage"}, {name:"zhName", image:"zhImage"}, ...]
}
```

If you don't control it, you can generate it from what you have once with something like this (untested, and it should be generalized to get the locales from the json):

```
var itemsByLocale = items.reduce(function (memo, item) {
  Object.keys(memo).forEach(function (locale) {
    memo[locale].push({name: item.name[locale], image: item.image[locale]});
  });
  return memo;
}, {en:[], fr:[], zh:[]});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should restructure your data:

```
items: {
    en: [
    { name: 'enName', image: 'enImage' },
    { name: 'enName2', image: 'enImage2' }
    ],
    fr: [
    { name: 'frName', image: 'frImage' },
    { name: 'frName2', image: 'frImage2' }
    ]
}
```

That way you only need to pull `items[country]` to get all the relevant items for that country.